# I'm using solr for address searching and I get different results depends on word order

Tags: solr, solr4

Is this correct behavior or do I need to do some extra setting?

I created custom filter where remove special characters and add synonyms

Answer (score 1):

the search in Solr is a two step process, first the documents are matched, and second they are scored for ordering the results. The scoring takes in account how near are one term to the other, so if the order of the words in the query change, the scoring is affected.

if you omit the storing of word positions with omitPositions="true" in the field definition, and then the search should not be affected by the word order. In the [Solr fields documentation](https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/indexing-guide/fields.html) you have many more options and how they affect the search described.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Doesn't help( Сlarification: I have different addresses, for example "650 E 76th Ave Apt" and I try to search as "ave 76" - nothing comes back, but if I enter "76 ave" - ​​I get some results

Comment: what is the fieldtype applied?

Comment: I created custom

Comment: You should post a screenshot or your custom fieldtype, but anyway, on the solr admin you have an analysis section than can help you to understand how both the field and the query are analized.

Comment: I created type field with this standart filters :<tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory * several different filters and <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" splitOnNumerics="0"/>
                <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="address_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true">. It`s for index and for query

Comment: well, handling synonyms is hard, and usually you should do only once, at index time or at query time, but no both. Did you use the analysis facility on the sorl Ui? if there's a problem you should catch there.